# Location of password in RAR archive

Tags: compression, zip, archiving

I have to extract a PDF  book  from a PW protected RAR file.

I successfully extracted the compressed file with 7-Zip, but when I try to open the decompressed PDF book I am asked for a PW.  There are a number of applications to retrieve the PW, but in order to better target my search I'd like to know where should I look for the PW: in the RAR archive or in the extracted PDF file? Some password retrieval applications are designed for PDF files and others for RAR/ZIP archives. Where should I look for?

Thanks

Comment: How uncompressed PDF is related to RAR archive where it leaves before? How piece of cookie related to its package? Fridge have no clue what it freezing... and so on...

Comment: First, you cannot retrieve a password from an encrypted RAR file. Encryption doesn't work that way. Second, your process indicates that the password is being asked by your PDF viewer, so thinking through your steps so far you have already answered your own question.

Comment: Alex, I really can't understand your question and how it relates to my issue. Perhaps it would help if you said something more ( and more specific!) than "..and so on.."

Comment: Alex, I inadvertently sent the comment before finishing: I'll will conclude by saying that even I can normally understand metaphorical or analogic language, still I can't see what bearing do your  cookie or fridge similes have on the relationship between " uncompressed PDF and "RAR archive", unless you want to be somewhat paradoxically witty..

Comment: music2myear, thanks for your comment,. 
You may be right, but then I wonder why  there are applications specifically designed for retrieving the PW from RAR,ZIP or PDF files. 
In fact I am already running  the RAR archive on 2 apps and I am waiting for the results. One is  called ARCHPR 4.54 and the other is KrylackRAR Password Recovery. 
But then, if the PW is located in  the extracted PDF file, I don't understand why the software returns a " nor supported or recognized file" message.  

Ittiandro

Comment: It's pointless looking anywhere for the password... because it is never saved. A hash is saved & when the correct password is entered, the hash of that matches the one stored. That way, nothing ever needs to know the password itself, only the hash produced when the correct one is entered.

Comment: Tetsujin, thanks for your input. Here is what Wikipedia says in their article "Cryptographic hash function"
quote The only way to recreate the input data (in this case the  PW, I suppose) from an ideal cryptographic function's output is to attempt a brute force search of possible inputs to see if they produce a match UNQUOTE

Comment: Tetsujin,  Wikipedia, in their article "Cryptographic hash function", says
quote The only way to recreate the input data (in this case the  PW, I suppose)......is to attempt a brute force search of possible inputs to see if they produce a match UNQUOTE    In fact both apps I am trying  hava a " brute force " search option. The problem is that the hash may not be in the encrypted/compressed RAR file, but in the extracted PDF file. If this is the case, I might well have yo give up. Thanks anyway Ittiandro

Comment: The most common method of password attacking is called a "dictionary attack" where a pre-created list of common passwords is tried against the protection. For extreme cases the cracker will also run through a list of every possible character combination, though this quickly becomes an exercise in futility as a decently strong password could take decades of attempts by the average computer to find the correct password.

Comment: In other words, they are not searching for and "finding" the password, they are simply trying a huge list of possible passwords and spitting out the results if/when they find the result.

Comment: Further, you have not yet clarified whether it is the RAR password you need or the PDF you don't have. As you have already decompressed the PDF we are assuming it is the PDF password you need. If this is the case, could you edit the question to indicate this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it is the PDF password , because if it was the RAR file that needed the p.w. I wouldn’t have been able to extract the PDF file. I also thought that the original size was 14 mb, but now it shows 0, which may explain the PW recovery software for PDF,  doesn’t recognize it as a valid file.

 I set the PW ( RAR)search for a length between 3 and 16 characters ( including numbers) : it has been running for 3 days with no result. Probably millions of combinations.It is pointlerss.I’ll give it a last try with the dictionary option, then  I think I’ll give up 
Thanks for the input Ittiandro

Answer (score 0):

If you have a normal PDF file that is not in an RAR file, and when you open the PDF it asks for a password, there is no way whatsoever that the password should somehow be part of the RAR file.

The PDF is locked/encrypted and you need the key to open it.

Answer (score 0):

If the password challenge shows at PDF opening then it's saved into the PDF file security settings.
If the password challenge shows at RAR extracting then it's in the RAR file.

Current standards for secured PDF files use AES-256 so good luck with that.